# MySql if then query

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to use if/then statements in mySql? I am looking to check the value of a column in a JOIN table and order the results based on the value of that column.

My sorry attempt:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM t1 
JOIN t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID
WHERE t1.ID = '888'
if(t2.col1 = '1') ORDER BY t1.tid ASC
else ORDER BY RAND()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CASE`:

```
ORDER BY
  CASE WHEN t2.col1 = 1 THEN t1.tid ELSE rand() END ASC
```

Beware the performance of this may not be so good, as MySQL won't be able to use an index for the order `t1.tid`.

You should also be aware that you can order by multiple things, so that possibly this will do what you want:

```
ORDER BY t1.tid ASC, RAND()
```

Also, you should keep in mind that `ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1` will actually fetch every row, calculate a random number for each, sort them, then finally just return the first row. So on data of a reasonable size, it will be slow (and also result in temp tables).